# Why does a parallel Java Stream with a short-curcuit operation evaluate all elements of the Stream while a sequential Stream does not?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream, short-circuiting

Consider the two test methods parallel() and sequential():

```
  @Test
  public void parallel() throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println( "parallel start." );
    IntStream.of( 0, 1 ).parallel().map( this::work ).findAny();
    System.out.println( "parallel done." );
  }

  @Test
  public void sequential() throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println( "sequential start." );
    IntStream.of( 0, 1 ).map( this::work ).findAny();
    System.out.println( "sequential done." );
  }

  private int work(int i)
  {
    System.out.println( "working... " + i );
    Threads.sleepSafe( i * 1000 );
    System.out.println( "worked. " + i );
    return i;
  }
```

Threads.sleepSafe() is a simple wrapper around Thread.sleep(), which swallows the exception and does nothing if 0 is passed.

When the test methods are run, the result is this:

```
sequential start.
working... 0
worked. 0
sequential done.

parallel start.
working... 1
working... 0
worked. 0
sleeping for 1000 ms ...
slept for 1000 ms.
worked. 1
parallel done.
```

`sequential()` operates as I would expect, but `parallel()` does not: 
I would expect `findAny()` in `parallel()` to return as soon as `work()` returns for the first time (i.e. for value 0, because it does not sleep), but instead it only returns after `work()` is also completed for value 1.

Why?

Is there a way to make `findAny()` return as soon as `work()` returns for the first time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parallel stream still supports short-circuiting, but there was be no advantage in using a parallel stream, if all threads were deferring their work until the thread(s) processing previous elements acknowledged that the operation has not ended.

Therefore, it is expected behavior that a parallel stream processes an unspecified number of elements more than necessary, as long as the final result is assembled correctly, i.e. dropping excess elements.

It’s just your example, consisting of only two elements, were just processing one element more than necessary can be interpreted as “all elements are processed”.

There’s generally little benefit in parallel processing when the number of elements is small and/or the actual operation is to find something that will predictably be among the first elements of the stream. Things get more interesting, if you do something like

```
IntStream.range(0, 2000).parallel()
    .map(i -> { LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(50)); return i;})
    .filter(i->i%397==396)
    .findAny();
```

---

Note that the terminal operation will wait for the completion of all worker threads before returning the final result, so when the evaluation of an element has been already started by the time a result has been found, that element’s processing will be completed. This is by design. It ensures that there will be no concurrent access to a source collection or other data accessed by your lambda expressions when your application code proceeds after the stream operation.

Compare with [the package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps):

> In almost all cases, terminal operations are *eager*, completing their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline before returning. Only the terminal operations `iterator()` and `spliterator()` are not; …

So a short-circuiting parallel stream does not process all elements, but may still take longer to return the already evaluated result when the other worker threads are still processing obsolete elements.

If you want an early return, accepting potentially still running background threads, the Stream API is not the right thing for you. Consider

```
private int work(int i) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println( "working... " + i );
    Thread.sleep(i * 1000);
    System.out.println( "worked. " + i );
    return i;
}
public void parallel() throws Exception {
    System.out.println( "parallel start." );
    List<Callable<Integer>> jobs = IntStream.range(0, 100)
      .collect(ArrayList::new, (l,i) -> l.add(() -> work(i)), List::addAll);
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    Integer result = pool.invokeAny(jobs);
    pool.shutdown();
    System.out.println( "parallel done, result="+result );
}
```

Note that this not only returns immediately after the first job completed, it also supports cancellation of all already running jobs via interruption.

Comment: I just used two threads in the example to make it as clear as possible. Adding more elements does not change the behaviour.

Comment: You are not using two threads, but two elements. You don’t control, how many threads are actually involved. But as long as the implementation uses more threads than you have elements, you will have at least as many concurrent invocations as elements. That doesn’t change with more elements. I never said that. I only said that *not all* elements are processed. When you have a significantly higher number of elements, you’ll be able to recognize that.

Comment: you wrote "the terminal operation will wait for the completion of all worker threads before returning the final result". That's what I'm experiencing, but I did not find it in the API doc. Can you point me to the corresponding documentation?

Comment: Good question. I always took it as given. I even remember a (now fixed) bug report regarding not waiting when an exception occurred (affected early Java 8 versions). After searching, I found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps): “*In almost all cases, terminal operations are* eager, *completing their traversal of the data source and processing of the pipeline before returning. Only the terminal operations `iterator()` and `spliterator()` are not; …*”

Answer (score 3):

Stream API in parallel mode is based on a [ForkJoinPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) paradigm, that uses max **X** threads by default (where **X** is equal to the number of available processors). If you will increase iterations count, you can check this rule.

Generally, default thread pool count for parallel streams can be customized in two ways:

- submit the parallel stream execution to your own ForkJoinPool: `yourFJP.submit(() -> stream.parallel().forEach(soSomething))`;
- change the size of the common pool using system properties: `System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", "20")` for a target parallelism of 20 threads.

> Is there a way to make findAny() return as soon as work() returns for the first time?

Basically the answer is **No** according to the idea of the ForkJoin algorithm. It "waits" while all the threads will fulfill their work. But as it was previously described, you can limit the number of workers to a single worker. Obviously it makes no scene, cause this approach is similar as sequential execution with additional overhead by redundant operations.

Comment: Maybe I do not understand your answer, but as can be seen from the output, the `work()` method is called concurrently i.e. there are enough threads

Comment: @sys64738 Updated with more detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want a parallel stream, then yes, it will call the `work` method several times concurrently.

Note that if your parallel stream has 1,000 elements and uses 5 threads, then `work` will be called at most 5 times by the parallel stream, not 1,000 times.

If you want to call `work` only once, then use a sequential stream.

Comment: I don't want `work()` to be called only once - I want `findAny()` to return as soon as the first `work()` returns.

Comment: @sys64738 It sounds like you expect the parallel stream to interrupt the computation of the worker threads as soon as one finds a matching element. But the stream has no knowledge of what you are doing. So you could have a global variable that you can use to check if something has been found and return from the `work` method manually when necessary. But that's something you will need to write.